# zend framework select join error getTable()

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-db, zend-db-table, zend-db-select

I am trying to implement this method in my model:

```
class Application_Model_MenuProfilesProducts extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract
{
    protected $_name = 'menu_profiles_products';

   public function fetchProducts($profileID) {
        $select = Zend_Db_Table::getDefaultAdapter()->select()
                        ->from(array('mpp' => 'menu_profiles_products'), array('NAME' => 'p.name', 'PRICE' => 'p.price*mp.added_value/100'))
                        ->join(array('p' => 'products'), 'p.id = mpp.product_id')
                        ->join(array('mp' => 'menu_profiles'), 'mp.id = mpp.profile_id')
                        ->where('mpp.profile_id = ?', $profileID);

        $adapter = new Zend_Paginator_Adapter_DbTableSelect($select);
        return $adapter;
    }
}
```

I get an error **Unrecognized method 'getTable()'**

Basically I'm trying to implement this SQL query:

```
SELECT p.name as NAME, p.price*mp.added_value/100 AS PRICE 
FROM `menu_profiles_products` AS mpp 
JOIN products AS p ON p.id = mpp.product_id 
JOIN menu_profiles AS mp ON mp.id = mpp.profile_id
WHERE mpp.profile_id = <a number>
```

Stack trace dump from zend:

```
#0 [internal function]: Zend_Db_Select->__call('getTable', Array)
#1 D:\wamp\www\Bucatarie\library\Zend\Paginator\Adapter\DbTableSelect.php(46): Zend_Db_Select->getTable()
#2 D:\wamp\www\Bucatarie\library\Zend\Paginator.php(755): Zend_Paginator_Adapter_DbTableSelect->getItems(0, 25)
#3 D:\wamp\www\Bucatarie\library\Zend\Paginator.php(584): Zend_Paginator->getItemsByPage(1)
#4 D:\wamp\www\Bucatarie\library\Zend\Paginator.php(1064): Zend_Paginator->getCurrentItems()
#5 D:\wamp\www\Bucatarie\library\Zend\Paginator.php(816): Zend_Paginator->_createPages('Sliding')
#6 D:\wamp\www\Bucatarie\library\Zend\View\Helper\PaginationControl.php(119): Zend_Paginator->getPages('Sliding')
#7 [internal function]: Zend_View_Helper_PaginationControl->paginationControl(Object(Zend_Paginator), 'Sliding', 'partials/pagina...')
#8 D:\wamp\www\Bucatarie\library\Zend\View\Abstract.php(342): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#9 [internal function]: Zend_View_Abstract->__call('paginationContr...', Array)
#10 D:\wamp\www\Bucatarie\application\modules\admin\views\scripts\menu-profiles\profile-products.phtml(44): Zend_View->paginationControl(Object(Zend_Paginator), 'Sliding', 'partials/pagina...')
#11 D:\wamp\www\Bucatarie\library\Zend\View.php(108): include('D:\wamp\www\Buc...')
#12 D:\wamp\www\Bucatarie\library\Zend\View\Abstract.php(880): Zend_View->_run('D:/wamp/www/Buc...')
#13 D:\wamp\www\Bucatarie\library\Zend\Controller\Action\Helper\ViewRenderer.php(897): Zend_View_Abstract->render('menu-profiles/p...')
#14 D:\wamp\www\Bucatarie\library\Zend\Controller\Action\Helper\ViewRenderer.php(918): Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_ViewRenderer->renderScript('menu-profiles/p...', NULL)
#15 D:\wamp\www\Bucatarie\library\Zend\Controller\Action\Helper\ViewRenderer.php(957): Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_ViewRenderer->render()
#16 D:\wamp\www\Bucatarie\library\Zend\Controller\Action\HelperBroker.php(277): Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_ViewRenderer->postDispatch()
#17 D:\wamp\www\Bucatarie\library\Zend\Controller\Action.php(523): Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker->notifyPostDispatch()
#18 D:\wamp\www\Bucatarie\library\Zend\Controller\Dispatcher\Standard.php(295): Zend_Controller_Action->dispatch('profileProducts...')
#19 D:\wamp\www\Bucatarie\library\Zend\Controller\Front.php(954): Zend_Controller_Dispatcher_Standard->dispatch(Object(Zend_Controller_Request_Http), Object(Zend_Controller_Response_Http))
#20 D:\wamp\www\Bucatarie\library\Zend\Application\Bootstrap\Bootstrap.php(97): Zend_Controller_Front->dispatch()
#21 D:\wamp\www\Bucatarie\library\Zend\Application.php(366): Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap->run()
#22 D:\wamp\www\Bucatarie\public\index.php(26): Zend_Application->run()
#23 {main}
```

Please advise.

Comment: Solved. I had to use $adapter = new Zend_Paginator_Adapter_DbSelect($select); instead Zend_Paginator_Adapter_DbTableSelect

Comment: Can you answer your own question in a way that would help others? If you do, you can select yours as the correct answer. It may seem strange, but it is preferred to deleting in situations like this.

Answer (score 2):

You need

```
$select = $this->select()
                        ->from(array('mpp' => 'menu_profiles_products'), array('NAME' => 'p.name', 'PRICE' => 'p.price*mp.added_value/100'))
                        ->join(array('p' => 'products'), 'p.id = mpp.product_id')
                        ->join(array('mp' => 'menu_profiles'), 'mp.id = mpp.profile_id')
                        ->where('mpp.profile_id = ?', $profileID);

        $adapter = new Zend_Paginator_Adapter_DbTableSelect($select);
        return $adapter;
```

OR if you want use Zend_Db_Select

```
$select = $this->getDefaultAdapter()->select()
                        ->from(array('mpp' => 'menu_profiles_products'), array('NAME' => 'p.name', 'PRICE' => 'p.price*mp.added_value/100'))
                        ->join(array('p' => 'products'), 'p.id = mpp.product_id')
                        ->join(array('mp' => 'menu_profiles'), 'mp.id = mpp.profile_id')
                        ->where('mpp.profile_id = ?', $profileID);

        $adapter = new Zend_Paginator_Adapter_DbSelect($select);
        return $adapter;
```